# Cassandra avoid ALLOW FILTERING

Tags: cassandra

I have a table of this type:

```
CREATE TABLE MY_TABLE
(
A TEXT,
B TEXT,
TOTAL INT,
PRIMARY KEY (A, B )
);
```

I need to make queries from key A and B separately.

Example:

```
SELECT sum(total) FROM MY_TABLE WHERE A='A';
```

In this one return me the correct result.

Example:

```
SELECT sum(total) FROM MY_TABLE WHERE B='B';
```

With this one I get the error of allow filtering.

```
InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Cannot execute this query as it might involve data filtering and thus may have unpredictable performance. If you want to execute this query despite the performance unpredictability, use ALLOW FILTERING"
```

How can I avoid using it? Should I separate the data in two tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Why do you get the issue ?**

There is something not obvious in the CQL Language: if the primary key is set up with a single parenthesis, the first argument is considered the partition key. So under the hood your table construction is:

```
CREATE TABLE MY_TABLE (
  A TEXT,
  B TEXT,
  TOTAL INT,
  PRIMARY KEY ((A), B )
);
```

You want to sum the items of the same partition to avoid `allow filtering` so yes only `A` works.

**How to fix this ?**

- **Multiple tables:** the most performant and you will end up MY_TABLE
- Create a table with **[counters](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql-oss/3.3/cql/cql_using/useCountersConcept.html)** to keep all totals
- Use a **secondary index** on column B